# Depth or Breadth first search?

Tags: search, artificial-intelligence

In the 8 queens problem which search would be more efficient in finding a solution, and why would this be the case?

For anyone who dosnt know what the 8 queens problem is, it is basically how to arrange 8 queens on a chess board (8x8) without them attacking each other.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

With First Fit Decreasing and Tabu Search and a bit of tweaking [OptaPlanner](http://www.optaplanner.org/) could easily handle the 5000 queens problem on an old laptop.

If I recall correctly, depth and breadth first search to scale above 20 queens. [Brute force doesn't scale beyond 12 queens.](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-docs/src/main/docbook/en-US/images/Chapter-Exact_methods/bruteForceScalabilityNQueens.png) Try it yourself, your mileage may vary.